# how to add one SIP Extension by command line in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I could add one SIP Extension  in FreePBX webUI like below:

Now I want to one sip extension by command  line. how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to add sip extension (entity) from command line.

You can add sip entity(peer/friend/user) in  `/etc/asterisk/sip.conf` `/etc/asterisk/sip_custom.conf`
Then reload sip module to take effect. cli command: `module reload chan_sip.so`

Comment: Thank you verify much , I will try it

Answer (score 0):

Freepbx is webgui. It not provide tool for that.

But you can use asterisk realtime architecture or change db and do amp_engine reload.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using asterisk cli, using something like this:

```
$ asterisk -rx "dialplan add extension 1111,1,Dial,SIP/170.21.20.100/1111 into local"
```